# Long-running service in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, service, architecture

I want to have a service in my Spring application that watches a directory for changes using the Java 7 WatchService. The idea is that when a file in the directory is changed, clients connected via WebSockets are notified.

How do I get a bean to run in its own thread as a service?

Comment: Create a bean with an `@Async` annotated method. Create the bean in an async configured Spring context and call the method.

Comment: Take a look at Spring integration. http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2013/05/spring-integration-file-polling-and.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Asynchronous execution.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support) With a correctly configured context (see the link), you declare a class like so

```
@Component
public class AsyncWatchServiceExecutor {
    @Autowired
    private WatchService watchService; // or create a new one here instead of injecting one

    @Async
    public void someAsyncMethod() {
        for (;;) {
            // use WatchService
        }
    }
}
```

Everything you do in `someAsyncMethod()` will happen in a separate thread. All you have to do is call it once.

```
ApplicationContext context = ...; // get ApplicationContext
context.getBean(AsyncWatchServiceExecutor.class).someAsyncMethod();
```

Use the `WatchService` as described in the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

---

If you don't have direct access to your `ApplicationContext`, you can inject the bean in some other bean and call it in a `@PostConstruct` method.

```
@Component
public class AsyncInitializer {
    @Autowired
    private AsyncWatchServiceExecutor exec;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        exec.someAsyncMethod();
    }
}
```

Careful which proxying strategy (JDK or CGLIB) you use.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm still very new to Spring, so this is very helpful.

Comment: @Joe You're welcome. Be careful to read as much of the linked doc as possible. Concurrency is not a simple concept.

Comment: Quick question, can you call the `@Async` method from your own `@PostConstruct`?